Object Tracking within a room
I've been given a research task at work that I'm getting a lot of conflicted answers on. Our requirement is to track a set of objects' (10 or so of them) locations in a room, not bigger than 30 feet by 30 feet. Ideally, we'd know the location within about 6 inches, and be able to gather around 10 data points per second.
My boss, when giving me the task, said he heard about hospitals using RFID bracelets to track exact locations within the hospital - accurate enough to determine if a patient fell. But in all of my research, I'm finding that RFID can, at best, track what room someone is in, not the location within that room. I have two questions:

Is RFID at all a reasonable tech to look into here? What sort of scanners/chips would we need?
If not, what would be a good method to track locations? My gut says Computer Vision would likely be best, but if there's other good tech to track exactly where an object is I'd love to look into it.

More than happy to add more detail here or ask on another forum. Thanks!
